# Syntax error when I access the "process.env" on Vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

I got a problem when I try to access the variable:process.env. It told me I got a syntax error and I'm 100% sure that my code is correct. 
I want to know what problem with it

I tried check my codes over and over again. I can't find any syntax error.By the way, it's ok when I access the `proceess` varible. But when I try to access the process.env, it started to execute `eval`, which raised the error I mentioned before.

My code goes that :

```
src/global.vue

console.log(process.env);
```

The error I got:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Object../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue (app.js:1170)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
    at eval (App.vue?9e04:1)
    at Object../src/App.vue (app.js:5245)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
    at eval (main.js:5)
    at Object../src/main.js (app.js:5357)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
```

The app.js:1170 goes that:

```
eval("/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__components_headers__ = __webpack_require__(\"./src/components/headers.vue\");\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__components_blogfooter__ = __webpack_require__(\"./src/components/blogfooter.vue\");\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n\n// import axios from 'axios'\n\n\n/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__[\"a\"] = ({\n  name: 'App',\n  components: { 'headers': __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__components_headers__[\"a\" /* default */],\n    'blog-footer': __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__components_blogfooter__[\"a\" /* default */]\n  },\n  created: function created() {\n    this.$store.dispatch('GET_BASIC');\n    console.log(Object({\"NODE_ENV\":\"development\",\"SERVER\":http://localhost:8000}));\n  }\n});//# sourceURL=[module]\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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\n//# sourceURL=webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue\n");
```

I solve it by adding double quotes on the value of the variable SERVER:

Old code

```
module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  SERVER: 'http://localhost:8000'
})
```

New code

```
module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  SERVER: '"http://localhost:8000"'
})
```

I don't know why it has no hint to tell me that thing. The grammar of config file is so weird that you need to put a quote outside an existed quote.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: If your code is 100% correct then you did not come there :)

Comment: I know that, I just want to express my worry.So it's exaggerating .
I stuck in the problem for a long time.

Comment: You should reduce your code to a MWP. I.e. the smallest state where the error still occurs. I can only say that in my vue application where I tried it, running `console.log(process.env)` works fine.

Comment: Are you using vue-cli or a custom webpack config? What's your webpack config?

Comment: @DecadeMoon Vue-cli.

Comment: @bodo I have. Seem that there is no person made the mistake like that.It's so weired

Comment: what is fn (app.js:89) && (app.js:1170)?

Comment: @Estradiaz To be honest, I didn't write it on my own. I think it's an auto generated script.

Comment: yes its bundled - but to understand this issue one has to recreate or at least read the parts - in e.g. chrome console you can click on those links in the brackets in the error and copy the code area

Comment: @Estradiaz Fine, I can show you what it said in app.js:1170. 
You can see it in the description of the question now.

Comment: it seems yor env variable `server: http://localhost:8000` is missing **"** should be `server:"http://localhost:8000"`

Comment: Where exactly did you make these last changes? I didn’t think such manual changes would be necessary...

Answer (score 1):

After instpecting the error in app.js:1170 one can see that your `process.env.server`somehow misses **"** - why that is no clue but i think this should be fixable now^^

currently:

```
{server: http://localhost:8000}
```

but should be

```
{server:"http://localhost:8000"}
```

Comment: I don't know where can I edit it. Every address used in my config file has been added single quotes.

Comment: Oh I fixed it. The value in the config file should add single quotes and double quotes like the NODE_ENV did.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when working in a project with webpack, I made a configuration of the `.env` to node and to the test environment, but when running in the web environment, this same error message, as if the process. env`did not exist. In my case I was using the dotenv lib, so it was pretty simple to solve, I just saw that the`JSON.stringify`setting in`DefinePlugin` was missing.

Resolved configuring it this way:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  "process.env": JSON.stringify(dotenv.parsed),
})
```